# how to insert data in a table with M-M relation table using SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello i am writing a insert script where two table are linked to other table which has M-M relationship, Here are my tables

Make

```
MakeId  Name
1       Suzuki
2       Bajaj
```

Class

```
ClassId  Class Name
1        Car
2        Bike
```

and another table which combines above tables as M-M

ClassMake

```
ClassMakeId ClassId MakeId
1              1     2
2              2     1
```

and there is another table called

OptionLevel

```
OplevelId       Name     Class      Type      Date
1               XYZ       A1         V       2022-03-01
2               ABC       B1         C       2022-03-01
3               PQR       C1         ALL     2022-03-01
```

and the OptionLevel and ClassMake is combined as M-M relation in another table called

ClassMakeOptionLevel

```
ClassMakeOptionLevelId     ClassMakeId     OplevelId
      1                     1               1
      2                     1               3
```

Here important that ClassMakeOptionLevelId is PK without identity so it is not auto incrementing

i have writtened following query to insert data but i am not able to autoincrement **ClassMakeOptionLevelId**  through the query i have used CROSS APPLY

```
DECLARE @VOptiontbl TABLE
(
 OplevelId  Int
)

Insert into @VOptiontbl (OplevelId)
SELECT OplevelId FROM OptionLevel OL 
where Date < '2022-03-01' AND Type = 'V'

Insert into ClassMakeOptionLevel (ClassMakeOptionLevelId,OplevelId,ClassMakeId)
Select (Select MAX(ClassMakeOptionLevelId+ 1) from ClassMakeOptionLevel ),* from @VOptiontbl B
CROSS APPLY 
   ( 
   SELECT ClassMakeId FROM ClassMake CM  
   Inner join Class C ON C.ClassId = CM.ClassId
   where C.ClassId = 1
   )  A
```

i want a answer to how i can optimize the above query also how i can able to insert **ClassMakeOptionLevelId** as it should autoincrement and for every record i am inserting should
have unique Id

Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: Create a view instead.

Comment: @jarlh i can make a view but that column incrementing is not happening that is my only concern

Comment: `ClassMakeOptionLevelId is PK without identity` Why?

Comment: Any kind of this type of roll your own identity logic is going to fail...period. There are many hacks you can do but they are still going to fail in some situations. If you want an automatically incrementing value either use an identity or a sequence. MAX(Field) + 1 is god awful.

Comment: Agreed. Why do you think you need to roll your own when sql server does it already (and better than homespun logic)?

Comment: "Roll your own" concerns aside, I have several observations. (1) Why are you selecting a ClassMakeOptionLevelId value based on Max of BrandProductBrokerOptionalExtraLevelId? (2) `MAX(xxxId) + 1` may be more efficient than `MAX(xxxId + 1)` by allowing a direct PK lookup. (3) If you may be inserting multiple records in one execution, you need to assign multiple distinct IDs possibly using something like `MAX(xxxId) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...)`. (4) For readability, suggest explicitly specifying the select fields 'B.OplevelId, A.ClassMakeId` rather than `*`. (5) Still won't be thread safe.

Comment: "... Still won't be thread safe ..." Hence the question - why do you believe you can't use an identity column?

Comment: @TN i have tried MAX(ClassMakeOptionLevelId) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) and it worked

Comment: Realize that databases are multithreaded and things that may *appear* to work in isolation may fail spectacularly in a production environment under load.